# Meu SQL não conecta

Tags: sql

Estou tentando criar um banco dedados após instalar o SQLDEVELOPER no linux UBUNTU 18, NO entanto ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

```
The Network Adapter could not stablish conection.
```

Comment: Questões de configuração de software, suporte e manutenção de infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su] ou [sf] conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).